# How do you overwrite the slds-checkbox_faux checked css

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, lightning-design-system

I am wanting to overwrite the css a toggling checkbox when checked.

```
.slds-checkbox--toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox--faux, .slds-checkbox--toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox--faux_container .slds-checkbox--faux, .slds-checkbox--toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox_faux, .slds-checkbox--toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox_faux_container .slds-checkbox_faux, .slds-checkbox--toggle [type=checkbox]:checked~.slds-checkbox--faux, .slds-checkbox--toggle [type=checkbox]:checked~.slds-checkbox_faux, .slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox--faux, .slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox--faux_container .slds-checkbox--faux, .slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox_faux, .slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox_faux_container .slds-checkbox_faux, .slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked~.slds-checkbox--faux, .slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked~.slds-checkbox_faux {
    border-color: #0070d2;
    background-color: #0070d2;
```

However lightning will not allow me to simply change the css files within the .css cmp, Nor does it seem to recognise the change within script tags on the cmp itself.

I have attempted to use the css class toggle function once the toggle is selected, But this is overwritten by the above lines anyway.

Ideally i want to change from:

[image: Existing Styling]

to:

[image: Desired Styling]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage the `$A.util.toggleClass` to add a CSS class when the checkbox is toggled. In order to do so, I would recommend you add an aura:id in order to find the element in your lightning controller,

```
<span aura:id="changeIt" class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
```

in your controller, simply find your component by id as specified in the documentation: [Finding Components by ID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_find_by_id.htm).

In your HTML input tag, you can add an  onClick Event to trigger an action, for example:

```
onclick="{!c.toggleClasses}"
```

the last part is getting the CSS to actually override the current background, by properly scoping your Css in order to have the background color change ( copied the selector path using my browsers dev tools):

```
.THIS #toggle-desc > span.slds-checkbox_faux.myClassOnToggle {
    background-color: red;
}
```

[image]

[Adding and Removing Styles](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_styles.htm)

Comment: Bah using the `!important` flag. There has to be a better way. **[`Specificity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)** should *always* be the preferred approach.

Comment: @Adrian Larson -> Fixed it, you forced me to not be lazy =P.

Comment: Damn, I was really close using the toggle then, Didn't know about !important so, 100 times new ever day. Thanks guys

Comment: @TimChadwick-> as mentioned above, try to avoid using !important, better scope your css appropriately. Dont be lazy like me, haha, I updated my post so you dont use this method

Comment: In general when overriding CSS, it's helpful to use Inspect Element in-browser to see the exact rules that are giving it the property you want to change. You need to make sure the specificity of your selector is higher. In some cases scoping it with `.THIS` still isn't specific enough.